# JAVA separate AES key, initilization vector and data from encrypted file with these 3 combinations used during encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have created encrypted file with combination of AES encryption, intilizatio vector and original data.
So my encrypted file contains above 3 elements in encrypted form.
Now during decryption i am stuck at separating all these 3 elements again, moreover i have to use AES key length hard coded during decryption that was generated during encryption.

```
public static void encrypt() throws Exception {

        // RSA with ECB mode
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, generatePublicKey(readKeysFromFile("My_public.pub")));

        // AES key generator
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128, srandom);
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

        // Initialization vector 16 byte
        byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
        srandom.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("dataFile" + ".enc")) {
            {
                byte[] b = cipher.doFinal(skey.getEncoded());
                out.write(b);
                System.err.println("AES Key Length: " + b.length);
            }

            out.write(iv);
            System.err.println("IV Length: " + iv.length);

            Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);

            File inputDataFile = new File("dataFile.xml");
            try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputDataFile))) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)inputDataFile.length()];
                in.readFully(buffer);
                in.close();
                byte[] encryptedData = ci.doFinal(buffer);
                out.write(encryptedData);
                out.close();
            }
        }

    }


public static void decryptRSAAES() throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, generatePrivateKey(readKeysFromFile("My_private.key")));

        File file2 = new File("dataFile.enc");
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file2, "r");

        // length of AES key 
        byte[] c = new byte[384];

        // read the AES key from file
        raf.read(c, 0 , 384);
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file2.toPath());
        byte[] keyb = cipher.doFinal(c);
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");

        // read the initializatoin vector
        byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
        raf.seek(384);
        raf.read(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        raf.seek(400);

        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("decryptedFileTest"+".xml")){

            byte[] decryptedData = ci.doFinal(fileContent);
            out.write(decryptedData);
            out.close();
            //processDecryptFile(ci, in, out);
        }
    }
```

Actual result: decrypted file is created with AES key and original plain data

Expected result: write only original plain data in output removing AES and initilization vector.

Comment: Try to make your methods more symmetric. You're not using `RandomAccessFile` during encryption, I don't see why you need it using encryption. You can use a single `FileInputStream`, right? The only other thing is that you need to read the full ciphertext after the IV, e.g. something like `readFully` used for the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify this and use the functions newly available in Java's `InputStream` classes:

```
public static void encrypt(RSAPublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("dataFile" + ".enc")) {

        // --- RSA using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        // --- AES key generator
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128);
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

        // --- write encrypted AES key
        byte[] encryptedSKey = cipher.doFinal(skey.getEncoded());
        out.write(encryptedSKey);

        // --- Initialization vector 16 byte
        SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
        srandom.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // --- write IV
        out.write(iv);


        // --- initialize AES cipher
        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);

        // --- convert file by copying to memory
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("dataFile.xml")) {
            byte[] buffer = in.readAllBytes();
            byte[] encryptedData = ci.doFinal(buffer);
            out.write(encryptedData);
        }
    }
}


public static void decrypt(RSAPrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {

    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("dataFile" + ".enc")) {

        // --- RSA using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        // --- read encrypted AES key
        byte[] encryptedSKey = in.readNBytes(determineEncryptionSizeInBytes(privateKey));

        byte[] decryptedSKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedSKey);
        SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedSKey, "AES");

        // --- Initialization vector 16 byte
        byte[] iv = in.readNBytes(128 / Byte.SIZE);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // --- initialize AES cipher
        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);

        // --- convert file by copying to memory
        File outputDataFile = new File("dataFile.xml2");
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputDataFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = in.readAllBytes();
            byte[] decryptedData = ci.doFinal(buffer);
            out.write(decryptedData);
        }
    }
}

private static int determineEncryptionSizeInBytes(RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
    return (privateKey.getModulus().bitLength() + Byte.SIZE - 1) / Byte.SIZE;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(384 * Byte.SIZE);
    KeyPair pair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    encrypt((RSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic());
    decrypt((RSAPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate());
}
```

As you can see the code is now very much more like a mirror image. I have simply copied the encryption code and then made changes to it. As you can see it now uses fewer classes by relying on `InputStream#readAllBytes()` (since Java 9) and `InputStream#readNBytes()` (since Java 11).

Note that you generally want to *stream* the file using a smaller buffer. As the entire plaintext *and* ciphertext are currently buffered your application uses much more memory than required. To encrypt data using streams you can rely on `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`.

Needless to say the exception handling needs improvement, I've simply looked at the best way to solve your current issue. Please take another look at it when you've got things working (get things working, get things right, get things optimized).

Comment: It worked for calculating length of keys, but not able to separate AES key, vector and  data from given solution.